# Argument of \begin has an extra }

Tags: errors, aastex

I've been emailed a 'sample' document that I'm supposed to cut/copy/paste to my needs. However, it seems like it's full of problems. The first thing that keeps coming up is:

```
./testit.tex:9: Argument of \begin has an extra }.
```

The document:

```
\documentclass{aastex}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\clearpage
\longtable
\begin{landscape}
\begin{deluxetable}{ccccccccccccccc}
\tabletypesize{\scriptsize}
\tablecolumns{10}
\tablewidth{0pt}
\tablecaption{\bf NGC 2264 members monitored with {\em CoRoT} and {\em
  Spitzer}}
\tablehead{
\colhead{Object} & \colhead{2MASS id} & \colhead{CoRoT id} & \colhead{J} & \colhead{H} &
\colhead{K} & \colhead{[3.6]} & \colhead{[4.5]} & \colhead{[5.8]} & \colhead{[8.0]} &
\colhead{[24]} & \colhead{Class} & \colhead{SpT} &
\colhead{H$\alpha$} & \colhead{Comp?}}
\startdata
CSI Mon-000007 & J06415304+0958028 & 223994721 & 12.22$\pm$0.02 & 11.53$\pm$0.03 & 11.18$\pm$0.02 & 10.12$\pm$0.00 & 9.74$\pm$0.00 & 9.32$\pm$0.00 & 8.75$\pm$0.00 & 6.20$\pm$0.03 & II & K7 & - & Y \\
CSI Mon-000011 & J06411725+0954323 & 223985009 & 12.83$\pm$0.02 & 12.05$\pm$0.03 & 11.55$\pm$0.02 & 10.49$\pm$0.00 & 10.07$\pm$0.00 & 9.69$\pm$0.00 & 8.82$\pm$0.00 & 5.60$\pm$0.01 & II & K7 & 58.30 & N \\
CSI Mon-006491 & J06392550+0931394 & 616920065 & 13.77$\pm$0.03 & 12.86$\pm$0.03 & 12.38$\pm$0.02 & 11.73$\pm$0.00 & 11.44$\pm$0.00 & 11.15$\pm$0.01 & 10.52$\pm$0.01 & 7.86$\pm$0.03 & II & - & - & N 
\enddata
\tablecomments{We have assembled a list of NGC~2264 region members,
  candidates, and field stars, called the CSI~Mon catalog. Here we
  show only the Mon identification numbers of objects discussed in
  this paper. The {\em CoRoT} ids are from the SRa05 run. H$\alpha$ refers to the equivalent
 width of the H$\alpha$ emission line, and we adopt the values of \citet{2002AJ....123.1528R} and \citet{2005AJ....129..829D}. 
  Spectral types are from \citet{1956ApJS....2..365W}, \citet{2004AJ....127.2228M}, 
  and \citet{2005AJ....129..829D}, Objects with the disk class II/III
  are have a class III SED based on the slope, but have significant
  evidence of a weak disk based on their [3.6]-[8.0] colors. The ``comp''
  column denotes whether the object appears to have a companion within
  1\arcsec (``Y'' if yes). Detection is based on visual binarity or elongation of the
  PSF reported by \citet{2009AJ....138.1116S}, or spectroscopic indications of
  binarity via variable radial velocity measured by \citet{2006ApJ...648.1090F}.
  Objects with no known companion (``N'') may still be
  undetected binaries. *Objects with IRAC staring data are marked with 
 asterisks.}
\end{deluxetable}
```

Why is it saying this? I don't see anything obvious (to me, at least).

Comment: Where is `\end{landscape}`??

Comment: Where is `\end{document}`??

Comment: Isn't `longtable` an environment?

Comment: what is `\begin{deluxetable}`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Package `longtable` defines an environment `longtable` that takes a mandatory argument, the specification for the columns. Thus the following token `\begin`
becomes the argument for `\longtable`.

Since a table is following `\begin{landscape}`, the previous `\longtable` is probably just a typo. If you remove it, the file compiles (after adding `\end{landscape}` and `\end{document}`.